# Trying to install php5-fpm on Ubuntu 14.04, getting error

Tags: ubuntu, php5

I am trying to install php5-fpm on Ubuntu 14.04 but I get an error I've never gotten before.

```
E: Package 'php5-fpm' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Have you enabled the universe repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the package you requested - `php5-fpm` is not available in the Ubuntu repositories (or any additional repositories you may have added).

`php5-fpm` is in the "universe" repository that is not enabled by default as it contains software that is not supported by Canonical. You can enable it by starting the "Software Properties" configuration (either though the software center or by launching `software-properties-gtk`) and select the second checkbox under "Ubuntu Software" which is helpfully labeled "universe".